# How do I create my own (non-CLR!) XML namespace for XAML?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml

Notice the Telerik namespace. It's not `clr-namespace:Telerik;assembly=Telerik` as you would expect. How did they do it?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sandbox.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: [Does this help?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and)

Comment: Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map one or more CLR namespaces to an URI, using the `XmlnsDefinition` attribute; for instance:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.yourdomain.com/schema", "MyProject.Foo")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.yourdomain.com/schema", "MyProject.Bar")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.yourdomain.com/schema", "MyProject.Baz")]
```

You can also use the `XmlnsPrefix` attribute to associate a default prefix for your namespace:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://www.yourdomain.com/schema/", "foo")]
```

Note that this attribute is only used as a suggestion for editing tools.

Comment: What's the advantage of using a URI based schema? sorry if I'm off the original topic.

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras, it allows you to declare a single XML namespace for several CLR namespaces. If you know that a given component is in a library, you don't need to remember in which CLR namespace it is declared.